# Backpatch to flow-of-control of FOR LOOP

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, intermediate-language

I am looking for Backpatching in FOR-LOOP.

I know this approach at IF-THEN-ELSE is in this way:

```
IF '(' expr M ')' stmt N ELSE L stmt L
{
   backpatch($4, $9 - $4);
   backpatch($7, $11 - $7);
}
```

You can use these markers in your answer:

```
FOR '(' expr ';' L expr M N ';' L expr N ')' L stmt N L
```

Please explan your answer.

Comment: What is the software you're using for this task? Which version of yacc? Do you have the source code for the IF-THEN-ELSE version? What are the parameters of backpatch(x, y)? I assume that $N are references to your grammar symbols. Aside: why do you have "L stmt L" and not just "stmt L"?

Comment: @battlmonstr: `L` is apparently a rule that inserts a label for branching purposes, so we need one before the else statement for the false part of the test to branch to, and one after the else for `N` to branch to. However, this entire question appears to me to be homework.

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question. Please read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)" and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Backpatching is an assembler concept; there is no reason for it in the intermediate representation of the higher level language. Backpatching allows an instruction such as a jump to refer to a label which occurs later. The label's address is not known at the time when we assemble the jump, so we just put zeros (or whatever) for the address/offset and keep a record. Later when we see the label, and its address is assigned, we put that address back into that jump instruction: that is backpatching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `FOR '(' expr1 ';' L1 expr2 ';' L2 expr3 N1 ')' L3 stmt N2`
we will have this scenario:

```
backpatch( $14 , $8 - $14 );
backpatch( $10 , $5 - $10 ); 
backpatchlist( $6.truelist , $12 );
backpatchlist( $6.falselist , pc );
```

1. First line: When we are at end of LOOP (`N2`), we must jump to first of Increment Section of the loop (`L2`) to compute `expr3`
2. Second line: After computing `expr3`, must jump to first of Test Expression section `expr2`
3. Third line: if evaluation of `expr2` is true, jump to first of LOOP's Body (`L3`) to compute `stmt`.
4. Fourth line: if evaluation of `expr2` is false, processing the loop has been finished and we must jump the first instruction after LOOP which is accessible by `pc`.

In this condition the markers must be defined as this:

```
L1,L2,L3 :  { 
              $$ = pc;
            }

N1       :  {
             emit(pop);
             $$ = pc;
             emit3(goto_, 0);
            }

N2       : { 
             $$ = pc;
             emit3(goto_, 0);
           }
```

Comment: It seems that the semantic values of your grammar productions are instruction addresses? Bizarre.